# What do i put in onBindViewHolder to bind my models and populate my RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui, android-viewholder

Right now I'm just trying to use Firebase UI 3.1.1 to populate a recycler view. All the tutorials im seeing are outdated, and the ones that are dated are incomplete. This is what i have so far...

```
private void setUpFirebaseAdapter() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.LOBBIES);
    Query query = reference;

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions lobbyOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Lobby>().setQuery(query, Lobby.class).build();

    mLobbyAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Lobby, LobbyViewHolder>(lobbyOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LobbyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Lobby model) {
            holder.
        }

        @Override
        public LobbyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

what do i put in holder so i can complete the recycler view? Thanks!

EDIT. Here's my View holder class too

```
public class LobbyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    View mView;
    Context mContext;

    public LobbyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mContext = itemView.getContext();
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void bindLobby(Lobby lobby) {
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView)     mView.findViewById(R.id.lobby_name_text);
    TextView locationTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lobby_location_text);
    TextView sizeTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lobby_size_text);
    TextView priceTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lobby_price_text);
    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lobby_date_text);

    nameTextView.setText(lobby.getOwner());
    locationTextView.setText(lobby.getLocation());
    sizeTextView.setText(lobby.getTotalMembers());
    priceTextView.setText("Php " + lobby.getCost());
    dateTextView.setText(lobby.getDateText());
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final ArrayList<Lobby> lobbies = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.LOBBIES);
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                lobbies.add(snapshot.getValue(Lobby.class));
            }

            int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LobbyDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", itemPosition  + "");
            intent.putExtra("lobbies", Parcels.wrap(lobbies));

            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: holder.bindLobby should do

Comment: @Pavan thanks for the reply! Do i pass anything inside holder.bindLobby()?

Comment: The model object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing you're not inflating the layout view (onCreateViewHolder) too, Do it like this:

```
private void setUpFirebaseAdapter() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.LOBBIES);
    Query query = reference;

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions lobbyOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Lobby>().setQuery(query, Lobby.class).build();

    mLobbyAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Lobby, LobbyViewHolder>(lobbyOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LobbyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Lobby model) {
            holder.bindLobby(model);
            //here you associate the holder views with the model attributes
        }

        @Override
        public LobbyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, parent, false);
        return new LobbyViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: sorry, just saw you have a method to inflate the views, see the edit